# Php Regular Expressions Get user name and id

Tags: php, regex

How to extract all user name and id after @ and make link

```
Hello @[user name1](id:1) i'm @[user name2](id:20)
```

to be

```
hell [user name1][1] i'm [user name2][2]


[1]: http://dadasds.com/index.php?u=1
[2]: http://dasdasds.com/index.php?u=20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find this :

```
@\[(.*?)\]\(id:(.*?)\)
```

replace with this:

```
<a href="something" id ="\2">\1</a>
```

you will get a result like this:

```
Hello <a href="something" id ="1">user name1</a> i'm <a href="something" id ="20">user name2</a>
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/hI3xQ7

Answer (score 0):

Use this **[Regular Expression Pattern](http://tinyurl.com/lphavkw)**

```
/\[([^)]+)\]\(id:(.*?)\)/.
```

#### PHP

```
<?php

    $str="Hello @[user name1](id:1) i'm @[user name2](id:20)";
    preg_match_all('/\[([^)]+)\]\(id:(.*?)\)/', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
    print_r($matches[2]);   
?>
```

#### Result

```
Array ( [0] => user name1 [1] => user name2 ) 
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 20 )
```

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo CodeViper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/FhSYmP)</kbd>

---

Get Only **Username Pattern**

```
/\[([^)]+)\]/
```

#### PHP

```
<?php

    $str="Hello @[user name1](id:1) i'm @[user name2](id:20)";
    preg_match_all('/\[([^)]+)\]/', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);

?>
```

#### Result

```
Array ( [0] => user name1 [1] => user name2 )
```

#### Check this <kbd>[Demo CodeViper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/280xPT)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

A way with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$data = <<<'EOD'
Hello @[user name1](id:1) i'm @[user name2](id:20)
EOD;

$pattern = '~@\[[^]]+]\K\(id:(\d+)\)~';

$linkList = array();
$path = 'http://the.path.com/index.php?u=';
$count = 0;

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 
              function ($m) use (&$linkList, $path, &$count) {
                  $id = '[' . ++$count . ']';
                  $linkList[] = $id . ': ' . $path . $m[1];
                  return $id;
              }, $data);

$result .= str_repeat(PHP_EOL, 4) . implode(PHP_EOL, $linkList);

echo $result;
```